# for loop list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following for loop for a dataframe

```
# this is my data 
df=yf.download('AAPL', period='max', interval='1d' )

vwap15 = []
for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
        if(i>=15):
            vwap15.append(sum(df["Close"][i-15:i]*df["Volume"][i-15:i])/sum(df["Volume"][i-15:i]))
        else:
            vwap15.append(None)
```

When I created the above for loop it generated a list.

I actually want to have it as a dataframe that I can join to my original dataframe df

any insights would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(df)):`. ;-)

Comment: this doesnt change the type

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like (right after the loop):

```py
df["vwap15"] = vwap15
```

Note that you will need to fix your `for` loop like so (otherwise lengths will not match):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
```

Maybe you want to have a look at currently available packages for Technical Analysis indicators in Python with Pandas.

Also, try to use `NaN` instead of `None` and consider using the [Pandas `.rolling` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) when computing indicators over a time window.

Comment: `df ['vwap15`]=vwap15 # did not work Ialso did the following and it gave me error. `df['VWAP']= sum(df['Close'].rolling(15)*df['Volume'].rolling(15))/sum(df['Volume'].rolling(15))`

Comment: @AMEXPO What does "did not work" mean? Can you share the error traceback?

Comment: @AMEXPO Please note my comment on your question above, use `for i in range(len(df))` instead so that `vwap15` and `df` both have the same length. ;-)